# I am having a problem with "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object"

Tags: babeljs, package.json

I tried uninstalling it, deleting the package.json file, I also tried adding to "devDependencies" but nothing worked. I can't deploy my application because of this thing. what should I do?

the message:

One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "parking-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the version of "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object". You've set it to a non-existent version "^1.0.0". Сhange the version to "^7.16.0" and then execute the "npm ci" command. After that, the annoying warning will be gone.